# How to use access token for expo when publish from CI/CD gitlab

Tags: react-native, expo, gitlab-ci, access-token

I setup the CI/CD on gitlab and I want to publish my app on expo, how can I do this? below is my current script for publish, it is completing without any errors but there is no updated build on expo, I think it is unable to login with token, is there any way I can publish the build using token?

```
script:
- apk add --no-cache bash
- npx expo login -t $EXPO_TOKEN
- npx expo publish --non-interactive
```

Any help appreciated !

Thanks
Asif

Comment: Hello, are there any updates on this? I'm trying to login to expo with EXPO_TOKEN but I'm struggling to use the EXPO_TOKEN to authenticate to Expo from Gitlab CI. Can you help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's as easy as `- EXPO_TOKEN=$EXPO_TOKEN expo publish --non-interactive`

Comment: I tried this, I am not getting any errors, but the build is not publishing and I am not getting updated changes on expo, any thoughts ?

Comment: Since it works for me, all I can do is to ask, what version of the expo cli are you using? do you install it on the ci runner?